# Make divs appear in same place onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 section divs that are hidden and when clicked they should all display in the center of the page however the last one shows further down than the others, I understand it's due to the nature of the flex box but what would the best way be to make sure they all appear in the exact same location?

JS - Another question, this script... Is there a more efficient way of writing it as I feel it is a little cumbersome for what it is doing, I just wasn't sure how else to write it.

```js
function about() {
  var about = document.getElementById("about");
  var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
  var work = document.getElementById("work");
  var blog = document.getElementById("blog");
  if (about.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    about.style.visibility = "visible";
    contact.style.visibility = "hidden";
    work.style.visibility = "hidden";
    blog.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    about.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}

function contact() {
  var about = document.getElementById("about");
  var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
  var work = document.getElementById("work");
  var blog = document.getElementById("blog");
  if (contact.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    contact.style.visibility = "visible";
    about.style.visibility = "hidden";
    work.style.visibility = "hidden";
    blog.style.visibility = "hidden";

  } else {
    contact.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}

function work() {
  var about = document.getElementById("about");
  var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
  var work = document.getElementById("work");
  var blog = document.getElementById("blog");
  if (work.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    work.style.visibility = "visible";
    about.style.visibility = "hidden";
    contact.style.visibility = "hidden";
    blog.style.visibility = "hidden";

  } else {
    work.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}

function blog() {
  var about = document.getElementById("about");
  var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
  var work = document.getElementById("work");
  var blog = document.getElementById("blog");
  if (blog.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    blog.style.visibility = "visible";
    about.style.visibility = "hidden";
    contact.style.visibility = "hidden";
    work.style.visibility = "hidden";

  } else {
    blog.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

header a {
  margin: 1rem;
}

main {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section {
  position: static;
  top: 50%;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="about" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <p>Developer, providing modern and responsive web development.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="contact" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <a href="mailto:macdevh@gmail.com">macdevh@gmail.com</a>
    <div id="social">
      <a href="https://instagram.com/machooper">I</a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/mac_hooper">T</a>
      <a href="https://gitlab.com/macdevh">G</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="work" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <div class="card">
      <img id="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <p id="card-title">Portfolio</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="blog" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <div class="card">
      <img id="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <p id="card-title">Blog</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. We are missing the navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rewrite

You want display none/block instead of visibility which takes up space

Vanilla JS

```js
window.addEventListener("load",() => {

  document.querySelector("header").addEventListener("click",(e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    e.currentTarget.querySelector("a.active").classList.remove("active")
    tgt.classList.add("active")
    if (tgt.tagName === "A") {
      const id = tgt.href.split("#")[1];
      [...document.querySelectorAll("main section")].forEach(section => {
        section.classList.toggle("show",section.id === id)
      })
    }
  });
  document.querySelector(".active").click()
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

header a {
  margin: 1rem;
}

main {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section {
  position: static;
  top: 50%;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

section { display:none  }
a { text-decoration:none }
.active { text-decoration: underline }
.show { display:block }
```

```html
<header>
<a href="#about" class="active">About</a>   <a href="#work">Work</a>  <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
</header>
<main>
  <section id="about" >
    <p>Developer, providing modern and responsive web development.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="contact">
    <a href="mailto:macdevh@gmail.com">macdevh@gmail.com</a>
    <div id="social">
      <a href="https://instagram.com/machooper">I</a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/mac_hooper">T</a>
      <a href="https://gitlab.com/macdevh">G</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="work">
    <div class="card">
      <img id="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <p id="card-title">Portfolio</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="blog">
    <div class="card">
      <img id="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <p id="card-title">Blog</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $("header").on("click", "a",function(e) {
    const $parent = $(this).closest("header");
    $("a",$parent).removeClass("active")
    $(this).addClass("active")
    const id = this.href.split("#")[1];
    $("main section").each(function()  {
        $(this).toggle(this.id === id)
    })
  });
  $(".active").click()
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

header a {
  margin: 1rem;
}

main {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section {
  position: static;
  top: 50%;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

section { display:none  }
a { text-decoration:none }
.active { text-decoration: underline }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<a href="#about" class="active">About</a>   <a href="#work">Work</a>  <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
</header>
<main>
  <section id="about" >
    <p>Developer, providing modern and responsive web development.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="contact">
    <a href="mailto:macdevh@gmail.com">macdevh@gmail.com</a>
    <div id="social">
      <a href="https://instagram.com/machooper">I</a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/mac_hooper">T</a>
      <a href="https://gitlab.com/macdevh">G</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="work">
    <div class="card">
      <img id="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <p id="card-title">Portfolio</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="blog">
    <div class="card">
      <img id="card-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <p id="card-title">Blog</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Display Block worked great. Thank you, as soon as I read display block I realised I could remove the flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and custom HTML5 attributes for these purposes.

In the CSS, I am creating a class called "hide":

```
.hide { display: none !important; }
```

In your HTML5 code you can include additional attribute (for example **data-toggleable**) for sections:

```
<section id="work" class="hide" data-toggleable="true">
```

Then in the JS code, you can hide all elements that have the **data-toggleable** attribute set to true with a single jQuery construct:

```
$(this).find('[data-toggleable="true"]').addClass('hide');
```

That one line will find all HTML elements that have the **data-toggleable** attribute set to "true" and will make them invisible. The great thing is that it will not assign the class twice (if the element already has the class 'hide', jQuery will not assign it again). Finally, you can show only the section ID that you want to be shown:

```
$('#work').removeClass('hide');
```

Comment: There is no need for jQuery. See my answer

Comment: Of course, there is no need for any library whatsoever. It just makes it a lot cleaner, faster, more understandable and easier to maintain (for me at least). Also, by using the custom HTML attributes and initial class assignment in the HTML, you will not need the "onload" function -> less complication there as well.

Comment: If you move my script to the end, there will not be a need for the load either. It is working exactly like the $(function() {}) you also do not need if the script is at the end of the page. I have almost completely stopped using jQuery

Comment: PS: My code works without changing OPs HTML except for removing the inline styles as they should be